# Catching an unhandled exception in ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, asp.net-web-api2

In ASP.NET Web API 2 I understand there are several different ways to catch unhandled exceptions, but I've apparently missed one because there's an error I see show up in the Output log while running locally that is not caught by any of my exception handlers.

Background:

I'm getting the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

The error originates from the `.Dispose()` method of my implementation of `IDependencyResolver`. The error is thrown randomly throughout operation, and not on start-up.

In `WebApiConfig`:

```
config.DependencyResolver = new MyResolver(); // MyResolver.Dispose() randomly throws the error
```

Now, I also have registered a custom `IExceptionLogger` and a custom `IExceptionHandler`:

```
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new MyExceptionLogger());
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new MyExceptionHandler())
```

that inherit from `ExceptionLogger` and `ExceptionHandler`, respectively. They override the `Log` and `Handle` methods (respectively, again), and neither of these caught the thrown exception.

I also have registered an `Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs args)` in `global.asax.cs`, and that didn't catch the exception either.

Where else am I missing an exception listener? I'd like to get as full of coverage as I can on the solution so I don't miss any exceptions and I can at least log them all.